# If humans were able to domesticate Azhdarchidae, would humans be able to get them Jurrasic World size?

Tags: biology, dinosaurs

If humans selectively breed Azhdarchidaes, would humans be able to make them absolutely massive? Could humans breed them to be able to carry a pilot and fly them?
[image]

Comment: See also https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/819/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-flying-creature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No

Quetzalcoatlus is already close to several theoretical limits for flying animals.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13752-013-0118-y

https://www.palass.org/careers/phd-opportunity/phd-pterosaur-flight-biomechanics-how-did-largest-airborne-animals-get-ground

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246692156_Limitations_on_animal_flight_performance

Comment: Is there a study about that? If so, could you link it? Im curious about that kind of stuff.

Comment: there is a preexisting question that has good answers to this https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/819/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-flying-creature

Comment: @sage the biggest problems are the stresses on the wing, loading on wings scales faster than length, the other big problem is take off, getting airborne is harder than flying.