# What type of organ would a animal need to breathe fire?

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution

Ok, so I was wondering if an animal ever evolved to the point that it had the capabilities to breathe or shoot fire say up to 300-500 degrees. What would it need to protect itself from its own heat as well as able to use it as a hunting tool?

Would it be something similar to spitting cobra or would it have around 3 different organs that store a key component for fire breathing? Would it have an air sack, some type of gas pocket, a "spark" component near its mouth?

Comment: Related: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/11306/627, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/313/627.

Comment: also related (identical?) https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/86887/is-this-fire-breathing-creature-possible

Answer (score 4):

Thought Not Fire as you want in Nature the [Bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle) creates  small explosions. If your creature use the Explosion to spread a spray of [Ethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol) from a third gland and a spark you get the flame you want with the explosion if the Ethanol mixed as a fuel air bomb. Honestly I do not see any living like that naturally though.

Comment: Anne McCaffery dragons

Comment: Real world example from which a believable story can be built.  Excellent.