# Dragon evolving from humanoid: Ice dragon

Tags: alternate-worlds, dragons

On an Earth-like planet, there were humanoids. They themselves evolved from reptiles. Now, this is happening in reverse. That is humanoids are turning into reptiles. But not your ordinary reptile. The humanoids are turning into dragons of all different kinds.

Ice dragons have the ability to freeze anything with their breath. Because of this, they can cryopreserve dying dragons until a medical dragon comes by to heal the dragons. This can be from a few minutes to years. Ice dragon eggs can only hatch in really cold places.

Development:

All dragons come from eggs although certain things trigger hatching and others delay or stop it. Once the egg has hatched the dragon is tiny compared to its mother and gets nutrients from stuff close by. For Ice dragons, it is food that is frozen by their mom. The dragon gets longer and taller. The back legs grow faster than the front legs and a few years later those front legs become arms. 2 more limbs then start developing halfway between the legs and arms. These limbs eventually develop into wings. From this point, it is just size and mass respectively that changes until it is an adult. Mating habits differ from species to species. Ice dragons make a big nest and freeze it. The number of eggs in a clutch also differs from species to species. Ice dragons only have 1 egg in a clutch.

How would Ice dragons freeze anything with their breath other than themselves?

Comment: Something's a little unclear, i think. In this world humanoids are reptiles, instead of mammals, and are spontaneously transforming into dragons? Sounds like the answer to all your questions is, "Magic!"

Comment: I recommend the separation of this into multiple questions as many of these will take a lot of discussion as there is no defined limits to the lore of your world yet.  However, the general answer to each question is simply adaptation.  Evolution is driven by a catalyst and, for your world, it could be something along the lines of prey animals adapting to your sentient, humanoid reptiles.  This would drive the reptiles to develop abilities to counter the various adaptations of their prey.  Example: your fire dragons don't burn themselves because they have clearly adapted to heat very well.

Comment: I agree with James that you should break these out into a lot of different questions. There have been a lot of dragon questions on here, so you may find that some of the answers already work for what you want, but not all in one place. [Here's mine for fire breathing](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/11689/6751). You'll get a lot more quality answers by breaking it out, and it will totally be worth your time.

Comment: You asked only one question, @Caters, so I answered it, as it looks like you worked out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

*Freezing dragon breath has been outlined in many answers for many posts but...*

**Chemicals**

1. Cryogenic chemicals at low temp, e.g. oxygen, krypton, argon, methane.
2. Liquid nitrogen, as it freezes naturally on contact with a solid object.
3. [Ba(OH)2 8H2O] and [(NH4)(NO3)], which combine to freeze, and store seperately.
4. Water stored in a sealed space at below freezing, forming ice on contact with anything.
5. Any number of other chemicals that react to remove all heat from a touched non-air object.

**Storage**

1. Keep it in a thermal-insulated container. It would be solid and tough, never quite decaying.
2. If it isn't already cold, keep it in a non-reactive gland by the mouth to spit it. Don't keep  in mouth!
3. Keep two chemicals that combine to react in separate containers and breathe together.
4. Contain a chamber that supercools a medium that can withstand the freezing point of the medium.
5. Just have really *cold* breath that slows and weakens things that get touched, no need to store.

Comment: I do think the dragon humaniod should be a bit bigger than a human, probably a bit wider than average human too since your characteristics needs adjusted anatomy for the dragonoid.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good examples/ideas for ice dragons in the series Wings of Fire. Possibly the best way to handle the whole freezing other things thing would be for the dragons to

- 1. Dump freezing water/ice mixture on victim. Not very glorious, but it works.
- 2. Literally freeze the air in front of them. As in absolute zero or just above the freezing point of air. This would only give a short range, but would freeze whatever they want.
- 3. Magic. No explanations necessary.